# Frequent urination caused by sound of running water

Tags: human-biology

I urinate at sound of running water when I brush my teeth or wash my hands . This only happens when I am home

Answer (score 0):

Very simply put, its the power of suggestion. You urinate, flush, wash your hands umpteen times together each day. So when you hear the sound of running water, you naturally feel the need to urinate.

Apparently, the sound of running water also help patients with lower urinary tract symptoms urinate ([reference](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0126798))